# Code coverage analysis: pass arguments to NUnit

Tags: nunit, dotcover

We want to run a dotCover analysis using the underlying NUnit test runner and currently have the following command line:

```
dotcover.exe cover /TargetExecutable:C:\Path\To\NUnit\nunit-console-x86.exe
                   /TargetArguments=MyAssembly.dll
                   /Output=MyAssembly.dll.cover
```

However, how to pass additional arguments to NUnit? We are especially interested in how to pass `"/domain:Multiple"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the `TargetArguments` argument is much more general than we thought. It is simply passed on as the command line argument of the target executable.

The solution is therefore very simple:

```
/TargetArguments="/Domain:Multiple MyAssembly.dll"
```